# How to make jQuery fadeIn/Out element smoothly move in and out of place

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets say I have this code:

```js
function hide(num){
 $("#text" + num).fadeOut();
}

function show(num){
  $("#text" + num).fadeIn();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="show(1)">
  Show text 1
</button>
<button onclick="show(2)">
  Show text 2
</button>
<button onclick="hide(1)">
  Hide text 1
</button>
<button onclick="hide(2)">
  Hide text 2
</button>

<p id="text1">
  Text1
</p>

<p id="text2">
  Text2
</p>
```

When you click "Hide Text1" Text1 fades away smoothly but Text2 automatically teleports to its position.
Is there a way to make this "teleport" more of a slide?

I know that I can animate every possible movement in JS but that gets really annoying when you autogenerate a lot of elements. Is there a way to do this for all of these automatic teleports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `slideToggle` and `animate`. The `slideToggle` handles the display and height of the element, while the `animate` handles the opacity. You may not need the `opacity` changed, so you could get rid of that. This will handle all the elements if they are dynamically generated.

```js
function hide(num) {
  var elem = $("#text" + num);
  if (elem.css('display') == 'block') {
    elem.animate({
      'opacity': 0
    });
    elem.slideToggle();
  }
}

function show(num) {
  var elem = $("#text" + num);
  if (elem.css('display') == 'none') {
    elem.slideToggle();
    elem.animate({
      'opacity': 1
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="show(1)">
      Show text 1
    </button>
<button onclick="show(2)">
      Show text 2
    </button>
<button onclick="hide(1)">
      Hide text 1
    </button>
<button onclick="hide(2)">
      Hide text 2
    </button>
<p id="text1">
  Text1
</p>
<p id="text2">
  Text2
</p>
```

I also added a check so the `slideToggle` doesn't fire if the user clicks on the `show` buttons and the elements are already there.

OR you can use `slideUp` and `slideDown`:

```js
function hide(num) {
  var elem = $("#text" + num);
  if (elem.css('display') == 'block') {
    elem.animate({
      'opacity': 0
    });
  }
  
  elem.slideUp();
}

function show(num) {
  var elem = $("#text" + num);
  if (elem.css('display') == 'none') {
    elem.animate({
      'opacity': 1
    });
  }
  elem.slideDown();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="show(1)">
      Show text 1
    </button>
<button onclick="show(2)">
      Show text 2
    </button>
<button onclick="hide(1)">
      Hide text 1
    </button>
<button onclick="hide(2)">
      Hide text 2
    </button>
<p id="text1">
  Text1
</p>
<p id="text2">
  Text2
</p>
```

OR, if you can change your code, I may recommend created a single `show/hide` button for each text box. Like this:

```js
function show_hide(num) {
  var elem = $("#text" + num);
  elem.slideToggle('slow', function() {
    if (elem.css('display') == 'none') {
      elem.animate({
        'opacity': 0
      });
    } else {
      elem.animate({
        'opacity': 1
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="show_hide(1)">
      Show or Hide text 1
    </button>
<button onclick="show_hide(2)">
      Show or Hide text 2
    </button>
<p id="text1">
  Text1
</p>
<p id="text2">
  Text2
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it using the `animate()` function in jQuery.
Here is your code:

```js
function hide(num){
 $("#text" + num).fadeOut();
  if(num == 1) {
   $("#text2").animate({
     top: "25px"
    }, 500, function() {
     
    });
  }
  
  if(num == 2) {
   $("#text1").animate({
     top: "25px"
    }, 500, function() {
     
    });
  }
}

function show(num){
  $("#text" + num).fadeIn();
    
    if(num == 1) {
   $("#text2").animate({
     top: "100px"
    }, 500, function() {
     
    });
  }
  
  if(num == 2) {
   $("#text1").animate({
     top: "25px"
    }, 500, function() {
     
    });
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  position: absolute;
}

#text2 {
  top: 100px;
}

#text1 {
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<button id="button1" onclick="show(1)">
Show text 1
</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="show(2)">
Show text 2
</button>
<button id="button3" onclick="hide(1)">
Hide text 1
</button>
<button  id="button4" onclick="hide(2)">
Hide text 2
</button>
<p id="text1">
Text1
</p>
<br>
<p id="text2">
Text2
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/rNOBLzL